# Elasticsearch in lumen giving empty Items in Resulted Data

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, lumen

I am working with Elasticsearch in lumen for simple search.

I followed Elastic search installation tutorial from : https://medium.com/@basemkhirat_88244/laravel-lumen-flexible-elasticsearch-query-builder-inspired-from-eloquent-bb5221c65af8

And In my `controller.php`

```
public function search() {
    $users = \Basemkhirat\Elasticsearch\Facades\ES::index('user_index')->type("text")->body([
        "query" => [
             "bool" => [
                 "must" => [
                     [ "match" => [ "name" => "Leena Patel" ] ],
                 ]
             ]
         ]
    ])->get();
    dd($users);        
}
```

And in my `routes.php` file

```
$app->get('/search', 'Controller@search');
```

My `es.php` configuration file :

```
return [

'default' => env('ELASTIC_CONNECTION', 'default'),

'connections' => [

    'default' => [

        'servers' => [

            [
                "host" => env("ELASTIC_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
                "port" => env("ELASTIC_PORT", 9200),
                'user' => env('ELASTIC_USER', ''),
                'pass' => env('ELASTIC_PASS', ''),
                'scheme' => env('ELASTIC_SCHEME', 'http'),
            ]

        ],

        'index' => env('ELASTIC_INDEX', 'user_index'),

        // Elasticsearch handlers
        // 'handler' => new MyCustomHandler(),
    ]
],

'indices' => [

    'user_index' => [

        "aliases" => [
            "user_index_alias"
        ],

        'settings' => [
            "number_of_shards" => 1,
            "number_of_replicas" => 0,
        ],

        'mappings' => [
            'users_schema' => [
                "properties" => [
                    'name' => [
                        'type' => 'text'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]

    ]

]

];
```

When running `/search` link in browser it shows result array like

```
Basemkhirat\Elasticsearch\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [total] => 0
    [max_score] => 
    [took] => 1
    [timed_out] => 
    [scroll_id] => 
    [shards] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 1
            [successful] => 1
            [skipped] => 0
            [failed] => 0
        )

)
```

My Question is **Why My Items array is empty even though there is data with name = Leena Patel** ?

Please help! I am learning ElasticSearch!

**Edit :**

My Database table users that contains column name with data Leena Patel SO i want this record in my items result

[image]

Comment: you haven't set index in your query

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta after adding index also same result.

Comment: may i know what is your main index name

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta  index name is `user_index`

Comment: I think it is missing something like do i need to add something in my User Model. It may be missing connection to `users` table . How it recognize that i need to search from `users` table?

Comment: if it was connection error then it'll return connection error

Comment: i think its a problem to define your main elastic database

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta Can you give me any guidence link for lumen elasticsearch?

Comment: `https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch ` may it'll help you

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta thank you will check this link :)

Comment: Can you show a document that should match but doesn't?

Comment: Please check my edited question @Val

Comment: I would like to see the document in ES, not the record from the DB

Comment: I really dont know which type of document ! can you please explain @Val

Comment: Elasticsearch cannot search inside your MySQL database. You first need to send your DB records to an Elasticsearch server in order to search them. So far, you've created your index, but have you sent your DB records to ES yet?

Comment: No how to send DB records to ES server? currently my ES server is running on localhost:9200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below link for elastic search

```
https://appdividend.com/2018/06/30/laravel-elasticsearch-tutorial-example/
```

then follow below steps for lumen

```
1) Move config directory to root alongside with app folder
```

> vendor\elasticquent\elasticquent\src\config

```
2) Remove comment from `$app->withEloquent();` in bootstrap\app.php of lumen folder
3) Register elasticquent in app.php file of lumen folder as below
```

> $app->configure('elasticquent');

```
4) Run command in your lumen folder
```

> composer dump-autoload

After these steps you need to set route in web.php of lumen folder

for i.e.

```
use App\Article;    // Use at top of web.php

$router->get('article', function() {

    Article::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null); // Using this code create command 
    Article::reindex(); // Reindex article indices

    $articles = Article::searchByQuery(['match' => ['title' => 'Android']]);   
    return $articles;
});
```